# redirect URL by country code

Tags: php

I want to redirect URL by Country  code .........

In my case My URL look Like

```
http://www.orchidkart.com/test/IN/home.php
```

if i add US instead of IN , My URL redirect Automatically on this

```
http://www.orchidkart.com/test/IN/home.php
```

if i add any other country ,My url redirect on specific country wise url

index.php file :

```
<?php
function getLocationInfoByIp(){
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = @$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $result  = array('country'=>'');
    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $client;
    }elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
        $ip = $forward;
    }else{
        $ip = $remote;
    }
    $ip_data = @json_decode
(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));    
    if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null){
        $result['country'] = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryCode;
    }
    return $result;
}

$result= getLocationInfoByIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$cont = $result['country'];


header('Location: '.$cont.'/home.php');




?>
```

Comment: you mean you are redirected to IN every time ? instead of selected coutry ??

Comment: you need orchidkart.com/test/US/home.php
but it is redirecting on orchidkart.com/test/IN/home.php ??

m i right

Comment: what error come in your code ?

Comment: Do you get correct country code from `$result['country']` ?

Comment: Another main thing, You are passing `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and defined as void... see your question.